# php gapi analytics reporting dimensions

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am building a Google Analytics dashboard for my custom CMS and I am kind of confused about how the dimensions effect the reports from gapi.

I am tracking `pageViews`, `visits`, `percentNewVisits`, `avgTimeOnSite`, and `newVisits` as my metrics and as of right now I have only `date` as my dimensions. When I only have `date` in the dimensions parameter it displays ALL the data from the past 30 days, even when all the data is 00:00 (no one visited the site that day)

When I ADD `landingPagePath` to the dimensions along with `date`, it displays ONLY the days that actually had numbers.

My question is this:

How does adding `landingPagePath` to my dimensions effect the data returned by GAPI and why does it change the amount of data shown but not change the data?

Also, on another reporting page, I am trying to get the data for only three specific pages using GAPI's filters. However when I have `ga:pagePath=~equipment/*,ga:pagePath=~online-store/*,ga:pagePath=~store/*` for my query it doesn't return anything. How can I return data for these three pages only?

**EDIT:** Even when using the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) with the exact same filters, dimensions and metrics as in my custom dashboard it displays the proper data.

My first question is more important if you have to chose one to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *landingPagePath* were added to the dimensions there were two dimensions. Assume that we got '20' different landingPagePaths and '25' dates, then we got 20 * 25 = 500 query result. Meant that a landing page has 25 records as a dimension.

Second question: you wrote wrong regulars.
Should be: ga:pagePath=~equipment/.*,ga:pagePath=~online-store/.*,ga:pagePath=~store/.*
or better: ga:pagePath=~(equipment|online-store|store)/.*

Comment: Thank you!The `ga:pagePath=~(equipment|online-store|store)/.*` worked perfectly!